# Dimension of the irreducible components of intersection of a projective variety with zero set of homogeneous polynomial.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, projective-varieties

Let $W\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety and $F_1,F_2,\ldots F_r$ be homogeneous polynomials of degree $>0$. Let $G$ be any irreducible component of $Z(F_1,F_2,\ldots F_r)\cap W$.

**Q) Prove that $dim~G\geq dim~W-r$.**

**Q) Prove that if $W$ is quasi projective and $Z(F_1,F_2,\ldots F_r)\cap W\neq \emptyset$ then also the above result holds true.**

Comment: A hint for the first question is to show that every equation can reduce the dimension by at most one. You can make this precise using Krull's principal ideal theorem.

Comment: Yes, for the projective variety case I can use the fact that height of minimal prime divisors have height less than equal to r. But it is not clear to me for quasi projective variety.

Comment: Try considering the Zariski closure of the quasi-projective variety